# Twitter bootstrap forms "collapse" when using custom font

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just added twitter bootstrap to my website, but it does not seem like it works the way I want it to on the form fields that use custom fonts. The form inputs get pushed to a smaller height, and the content is cut off. Adding height does not help either.

I need to fix this somehow.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a larger `height` and `line-height`.

For example:

```
.input-medium {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

[image: fixed text box]