# TW Bootstrap Custom Fonts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would just like to ask if anybody would be able to take me step by step through how to get custom fonts working with TW Bootstrap?

Cheers Guys

Comment: What do you mean by custom fonts? Search for "font-family" in bootstrap.css and replace it? Or did you meant something else?
Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996612/twitter-bootstrap-forms-collapse-when-using-custom-font?rq=1

Comment: When I say custom fonts I mean like those not found in Bootstrap, such as from Google Fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add some css using the `*` (wildcard) element:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono);

* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82W9K/)

Comment: Thanks, this also sorted a problem I was having with colours.... But do you know how to make the background colour of a thumbnail transparent please?  This would really help me....

Answer (score 1):

you could go with what @Lando suggested or try adding this in the header

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

make it universal

```
* {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

}

or add a custom class

```
.custom_Class {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

}